# Windows 11: OpenVPN service failing to stat at boot

Tags: windows, openvpn, service

I have an OpenVPN profile installed in `config-auto` directory on my Windows 11 machine, so that it connects to my OpenVPN server at boot.

The problem is that **sometimes** at system startup, it starts failing to connect with:

```
2022-03-11 09:27:38 [server] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
2022-03-11 09:27:38 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
2022-03-11 09:27:38 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
2022-03-11 09:27:43 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2022-03-11 09:27:43 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2022-03-11 09:27:43 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]<REDACTED>:1194
2022-03-11 09:27:43 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
2022-03-11 09:27:43 UDP link local: (not bound)
2022-03-11 09:27:43 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]<REDACTED>:1194
2022-03-11 09:28:43 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
2022-03-11 09:28:43 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2022-03-11 09:28:43 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
```

As if there is no internet connection, however you can see that my ethernet interface up and connected to the internet:
[image]

As soon as I restart OpenVPN service:
[image]

Everything starts working fine:

```
2022-03-11 09:28:43 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2022-03-11 09:28:43 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting

2022-03-11 10:16:36 NOTE: --user option is not implemented on Windows
2022-03-11 10:16:36 NOTE: --group option is not implemented on Windows
2022-03-11 10:16:36 WARNING: Compression for receiving enabled. Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Sent packets are not compressed unless "allow-compression yes" is also set.
2022-03-11 10:16:36 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-128-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-128-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-128-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-128-CBC' to silence this warning.
2022-03-11 10:16:36 OpenVPN 2.5.5 Windows-MSVC [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Dec 15 2021
2022-03-11 10:16:36 Windows version 10.0 (Windows 10 or greater) 64bit
2022-03-11 10:16:36 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021, LZO 2.10
2022-03-11 10:16:36 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2022-03-11 10:16:36 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2022-03-11 10:16:36 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]<REDACTED>:1194
2022-03-11 10:16:36 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
2022-03-11 10:16:36 UDP link local: (not bound)
2022-03-11 10:16:36 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]<REDACTED>:1194
2022-03-11 10:16:36 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]<REDACTED>:1194, sid=7818afbf 7c74fa3b
2022-03-11 10:16:36 VERIFY OK: depth=1, <REDACTED>
2022-03-11 10:16:36 VERIFY KU OK
2022-03-11 10:16:36 Validating certificate extended key usage
2022-03-11 10:16:36 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
```

I presume, it is some kinda race condition between my OpenVPN and ethernet interfaces. I tried reducing `InterfaceMetric` for my ethernet interface and increasing it for OpenVPN interface to no avail:

```
Get-NetIPInterface

ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- --------------                  ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
29      vEthernet (WSL)                 IPv6                  1500              15 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
12      Ethernet 3                      IPv6                  1500               5 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
10      Local Area Connection* 2        IPv6                  1500              25 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
24      Ethernet                        IPv6                  1500               6 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
22      Local Area Connection* 1        IPv6                  1500              25 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
23      OpenVPN                         IPv6                  1500              25 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
8       Ethernet 2                      IPv6                  1500               5 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
13      OpenVPN Wintun                  IPv6                 65535               5 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv6            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
29      vEthernet (WSL)                 IPv4                  1500              15 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
12      Ethernet 3                      IPv4                  1500               5 Enabled  Disconnected    ActiveStore
10      Local Area Connection* 2        IPv4                  1500              25 Enabled  Disconnected    ActiveStore
24      Ethernet                        IPv4                  1500               1 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
22      Local Area Connection* 1        IPv4                  1500              25 Enabled  Disconnected    ActiveStore
23      OpenVPN                         IPv4                  1500             100 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
8       Ethernet 2                      IPv4                  1500               5 Enabled  Disconnected    ActiveStore
13      OpenVPN Wintun                  IPv4                 65535               5 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv4            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
```

I also tried setting a recovery strategy on OpenVPN service, but it seems like Windows does not treat OpenVPN service failing to connect as broken thus is not restarting it:
[image]

Again, it only happens 1 in 5 boots, most of the time it works fine.

Searched all over the internet, but couldn't find anyone else having this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the solution helped resolve the problem.

Ended up uninstalling OpenVPN Community Edition, and installing OpenVPN Connect app instead.

To start OpenVPN Connect at boot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the service startup to "Delayed". It might be delayed, but at least it works. If that still does not work, try using another VPN client.

Comment: Hi, yep also tried that. Did not help.


Problem is it is an official OpenVPN community client. Idk if I could trust other unofficial builds :(

Answer (score 0):

I notice `Inactivity timeout` there so maybe this helps.

Open the [startup folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-app-to-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-10-150da165-dcd9-7230-517b-cf3c295d89dd) (hit Windows+R then type `shell:startup`), create a shortcut run `ping` to somewhere on the internet, say `ping 1.1.1.1` (`ping` is the app to run and `1.1.1.1` is the argument) just to make sure VPN doesn't get cut on startup.